# Expanding linear functional to base of $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear functional $f_1\in V^*$ where $V^*$ is a dual space of $V$, I can expand it to the base of $V^*$ : $B^*=\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}$, that I know. But does it mean that exist a base $B$ for $V$ such that for each $f_i\in B^*:f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$ where $v_i\in B, 1\leq i\leq n$ and $B$ is a base for $V$?
It seems obvious but if there is a way to prove it I would be happy to see.

Comment: Take $\{ f_1^*, \dots, f_n^* \}$ the dual basis of $V^{**}$. Since $V^{**}$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$, we have that $f_i^*$ corresponds to some $v_i \in V$. Then $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is your required basis.